# Best PHP login script?

Tags: php, authentication

Hey stackoverflow! I am building my first website with log in functionality and I was searching for a good log in script. However, googling just won't work because there are too many to choose from, so I thought I'd ask here.

What is in your experience a good login script that you often use? It will need registring options and e-mailing the new users etc. Also some different user levels might come in handy. Pasword encryption/salting and possibly good form handling as well.

What do you guys often use? thanks!

this any good?:
http://evolt.org/node/60384/

Comment: The linked example (from 2004) is certainly no good. It relies on magic_quotes or addslashes instead of using proper SQL escaping.

Comment: check http://php-login.net/, it's nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used http://usercake.com in the past, it is very good .

Comment: thanks, am looking into it right now!

Answer (score 8):

Write your own. At beginning it may be bad, but programming is the best way to learn. Even if it'll be totally useless or it will have many errors, it's yours. You can always read tips creating login script. I suggest you using `password_*` functions family, `bcrypt`, `pbkdf2`, or really just `password_*` functions.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I know it would be the best way to learn, but I don't have that amount of time right now. I just want to create a nice website in which I spend my time on the specific functionality of the website, not the periferal things that just need to be there. But thanks for your comment!

Comment: @up comment If you haven't time to create your site, use CMS. If you have, you must also have time to create login script because it's part of it.

Comment: I understand you, but since this is just a little fun side project for me, I don't have the time/motivation to learn making a system all over again. I'd like to focus on the things that make the site stand out and make it special. Don't worry, I'll have to learn how to program for this as well so in the end I might even develop my own login system. Just for now I want it to work quickly :)

Answer (score 2):

Try Zend_Auth, you have lots of choice for user database, mysql, active directory, ldap and ...